# Flexigrid only 30 records are being shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using http://flexigrid.info/ for one of my site. It is displaying only 30 rows . The records after 30 are not being displayed. Below is my code for Flexigrid

```
$("#" + id).flexigrid({
    url : PageUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    colModel : TableColModel,
    sortname : SortColName,
    sortorder : "asc",
    usepager : false,
    useRp : false,
    rp : 15,
    showTableToggleBtn : false,
    width : Tblwidth,
    height : TblHeight,
    showToggleBtn : false,
    singleSelect : true,
    preProcess : preProcessName,
    onSuccess : onSuccessName,
    onDragCol : onDragColName,
    onToggleCol : onToggleColName,
    onChangeSort : function(name, order) {
        sortGrid("#" + id, order);
    }

});
```

Please help me fix it. I don't want to set  `usepager : true`, because i want all records to be displayed in a single page.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It's been a while since I have used Flexigrid, but try removing/changing `rp`

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle with your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess after looking at the samples...

```
useRp: true,
rp: 1000,
```

I think this means `rowsPage` and then by setting this number either to your dataset size or larger it should display all the rows.  Or you could try removing the `rp` parameter all together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view all the result, set

```
rp : 100 //your total number of rows
height: 'auto'
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ws67j/30/)

Comment: this is more clear. commented and uncomment height in this fiddle, you will see the difference

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with the json response which i was sending so it was not displaying records. Thanks All for your time and special thanks to brombomb.